# Magento 1.9 auto select country

Tags: magento-1.9, countries

We only allow 1 country in our Magento store.
Now we load on a custom module the country selector, but this does not select the only country as default selection.

It currently show a select box with the following values. But we want to select NL as a default country. How can we achieve that?

```
<select name="billing[country_id]" id="billing:country" class="validate-select" title="Land">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="NL">Nederland</option>
</select>
```

Our code:

```
        <td class="p5 input-select">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->getAddedFieldName(); ?>:country"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Country') ?></label>
            <?php echo $this->getFieldRequiredSpan(true); ?>
            <?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect(
                $parent->getValue('country_id', $formType),
                $this->getAddedFieldName().'[country_id]',
                $this->getAddedFieldName() . ':country',
                Mage::helper('sales')->__('Country'));
            ?>
        </td>
```